# Transpose table and save as View

Tags: sql-server, view, pivot, user-defined-functions, unpivot

I have a dynamic `pivot`/`unpivot` script that transposes a table. This is dynamic enough to return certain columns that I want and using dynamic columns.

What I am looking for is rather to convert this into either a `UDF` or a `VIEW` so that I can join it to other tables.

Please help.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[uspGetUserByValues]
(
    @Select NVARCHAR(4000) = '*',
    @Where NVARCHAR(4000) = NULL,
    @OrderBy NVARCHAR(4000) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',P.' + QUOTENAME(PropertyDescription) 
                    from System_Properties
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

    set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ', M.Email, C.Company_Name, C.Company_Type_ID, U.UserName, ISNULL(SMS.SMSProfiles,0) SMSProfiles, U.UserID
                 from 
                 (
                    select PropertyDescription, UP.UserID, PropertyValue
                    from User_Properties UP 
                        JOIN System_Properties SP ON UP.PropertyID = SP.PropertyID
                        JOIN aspnet_Membership M ON UP.UserID = M.UserID
                ) X 
                pivot 
                (
                    min(PropertyValue)
                    for PropertyDescription in (' + REPLACE(@cols,'P.','') + ')
                ) P 
                JOIN aspnet_Membership M ON P.UserID = M.UserID
                JOIN aspnet_Users U on P.UserID = U.UserID
                JOIN Companies C ON C.Company_ID = P.Company_ID
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT UserId, COUNT(Users_SMS_Profile_ID) SMSProfiles 
                        FROM Users_SMS_Profile GROUP BY UserID ) SMS ON SMS.UserID = P.UserID
                '

    SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @Select + ' FROM ('+ @query +') A'

    IF ISNULL(@Where,'NULL') != 'NULL'
    BEGIN
        SET @query = @query + ' WHERE ' + @Where
    END
    IF ISNULL(@OrderBy,'NULL') != 'NULL'
    BEGIN
        SET @query = @query + ' ORDER BY ' + @OrderBy
    END

    execute(@query)

    --PRINT(@query)
END
```

Comment: You cannot use dynamic SQL inside a view or a UDF. You have to use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH wow I made it.

I know this is with "known" column names but actually I didn't have to know them.

Firstly, this is the query I used to create the View. I will need to drop the view at least every I add a new Property or I can actually write a job that checks if all the properties from System_Properties are represented in the view, if not then drop the view and run this code.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[uspCreateViewUsers]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',P.' + QUOTENAME(PropertyDescription) 
                    from System_Properties
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

    set @query = 'CREATE VIEW vwUsers AS SELECT ' + @cols + ', M.Email, C.Company_Name, C.Company_Type_ID, U.UserName, ISNULL(SMS.SMSProfiles,0) SMSProfiles, U.UserID
                 from 
                 (
                    select PropertyDescription, UP.UserID, PropertyValue
                    from User_Properties UP 
                        JOIN System_Properties SP ON UP.PropertyID = SP.PropertyID
                        JOIN aspnet_Membership M ON UP.UserID = M.UserID
                ) X 
                pivot 
                (
                    min(PropertyValue)
                    for PropertyDescription in (' + REPLACE(@cols,'P.','') + ')
                ) P 
                JOIN aspnet_Membership M ON P.UserID = M.UserID
                JOIN aspnet_Users U on P.UserID = U.UserID
                JOIN Companies C ON C.Company_ID = P.Company_ID
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT UserId, COUNT(Users_SMS_Profile_ID) SMSProfiles 
                        FROM Users_SMS_Profile GROUP BY UserID ) SMS ON SMS.UserID = P.UserID
                '

    execute(@query)
END
```

Them the View, which can't be represented graphically by table joins looks like this:

```
SELECT     P.[Company_ID], P.[Created_Date], P.[Created_User], P.[Cust_ID], P.[FirstName], P.[IPCheck], P.[JobTitle], P.[LastLogin], P.[LastModified_Date], P.[LastModified_User], 
                      P.[LastName], P.[Newsletter_OptIn], P.[Password_Change], P.[SupAdmin], P.[SysAccess], P.[SysAdmin], P.[User_Cat_1], P.[User_Cat_10], P.[User_Cat_2], 
                      P.[User_Cat_3], P.[User_Cat_4], P.[User_Cat_5], P.[User_Cat_6], P.[User_Cat_7], P.[User_Cat_8], P.[User_Cat_9], P.[UserClient_ID], M.Email, C.Company_Name, 
                      C.Company_Type_ID, U.UserName, ISNULL(SMS.SMSProfiles, 0) SMSProfiles, U.UserID
FROM         (SELECT     PropertyDescription, UP.UserID, PropertyValue
                       FROM          User_Properties UP JOIN
                                              System_Properties SP ON UP.PropertyID = SP.PropertyID JOIN
                                              aspnet_Membership M ON UP.UserID = M.UserID) X PIVOT (min(PropertyValue) FOR PropertyDescription IN ([Company_ID], [Created_Date], [Created_User], 
                      [Cust_ID], [FirstName], [IPCheck], [JobTitle], [LastLogin], [LastModified_Date], [LastModified_User], [LastName], [Newsletter_OptIn], [Password_Change], [SupAdmin], 
                      [SysAccess], [SysAdmin], [User_Cat_1], [User_Cat_10], [User_Cat_2], [User_Cat_3], [User_Cat_4], [User_Cat_5], [User_Cat_6], [User_Cat_7], [User_Cat_8], 
                      [User_Cat_9], [UserClient_ID])) P JOIN
                      aspnet_Membership M ON P.UserID = M.UserID JOIN
                      aspnet_Users U ON P.UserID = U.UserID JOIN
                      Companies C ON C.Company_ID = P.Company_ID LEFT JOIN
                          (SELECT     UserId, COUNT(Users_SMS_Profile_ID) SMSProfiles
                            FROM          Users_SMS_Profile
                            GROUP BY UserID) SMS ON SMS.UserID = P.UserID
```

This now allows me to query the View as if it was a table.

I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: This is a completely different problem. It dosn't require input parameters and logical solution here is a view. You have to update your question if you think it will help someone, otherwise a careless reader could spend his time unnecessarily.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean because I showed what Stored Procedure I had, which I needed to convert to a view so that I can `JOIN` the resulting table in a query. Yes you can't use parameters to create a view but now I can actually say `SELECT x,y,z FROM vwUsers WHERE a=b ORDER BY x`. The view will obviously store all the rows transposed, which is what my question is asking.

Comment: In your question you clearly state that there is a dynamic WHERE clause and you want to convert the query to UDF or a view. There are input parameters used in your WHERE clause and THAT is not applicable to a view. Your answer has no such where clause, and therefore avoids the key part that defines your question. If someone else provided such an answer, they would probably be downvoted.

Comment: Oh I am sorry I didn't realise. I wanted to say dynamic columns. I know a UDF/VIEW don't require WHERE clause. I guess my question was supposed to have been downvoted as it shows lack of understanding in UDF/Views.

Answer (score 0):

Simply said: *you cant*

At least you can't do it using conventional TSQL programming. Which means you would have to use some hack. Let me explain.

Closest thing to your SP would be UDF. However, UDFs are rather restricted. One thing UDF expect is for data to stay the same while and after executing it. Of course that this means EXEC() is forbidden in that scope.

Another possibility would be a view. However, you have a number of parameters and view's schema depends on these parameters. Functionality to change view's schema based on input parameters doesn't exist in SQL server.

And now for the hacks.

<s>One hack I can think of is:</s>

- create a CLR UDF
- create new connection based on context connection (same server, same db)
- exec your SP there
- return result to your original pipe

But it may or may not work (it's a hack after all).

If the hack doesn't work, you can try playing it by the book. This means creating a CLR UDF, assemble select statement in there and execute it, which means that you will have to throw away your original SP. However, it is not a hack since SQL CLR UDF's are made for such (and other) situations. Only thing you will have to take care about is using `SqlMetaData` because UDF doesn't have a predefined resultset. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlmetadata%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

In my previous answer I stated that it could be done using CLR UDF, but that was wrong. One thing I forgot is that Microsoft insists on providing a finite number of columns for UDF. This may not be obvious while developing in .NET - after all, you can return any number of columns to SqlPipe. See this (untested) code...

```
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
public static void DynOutFunc(SqlString select, SqlString where, SqlString orderBy)
{
    // 1: Create SQL query
    string query = "select db_id(), db_name()";

    // 2: Find out which colums and their types are part of the output
    SqlMetaData[] metaData = 
        {
            new SqlMetaData("ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int),
            new SqlMetaData("Database", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256)
        };

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        using (reader)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(metaData);

                SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart(record);

                for(int i = 0; i < metaData.Length; i++)
                {
                    if(metaData[i].DbType == DbType.String)
                        record.SetString(i, reader.GetString(i));
                    else if(metaData[i].DbType == DbType.Int32)
                        record.SetInt32(i, reader.GetInt32(i));
                    // else if's should cover all supported data taypes
                }

                SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(record);
            }
        }

        SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsEnd();
    }
}
```

Notice SqlMetaData collection that holds information about columns. What stops you from appending just another column to it?

**But(!)** when it comes to registering that function in the SQL Server itself, you HAVE to provide arguments, like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DynOutFunc 
  @select [nvarchar](4000), 
  @where [nvarchar](4000), 
  @orderBy [nvarchar](4000)
RETURNS TABLE (p1 type1, p2 type2, ... pN typeN)
AS EXTERNAL NAME SqlClrTest.UserDefinedFunctions.DynOutFunc;
```

It turns out there are no hacks for this I can think of. Or there are just no hacks here at all.

Comment: Can you perhaps give me an example? a guide of some sort?

Comment: @SollyM: example for what exactly? General CLR UDF? Or a hack?

Comment: I needed this done on SQL so that it is independent of the application technology. Basically we have ColdFusion andn .NET applications reading the same database and making changes together. The .NET code won't help in this regard.

Comment: SQL Server CLR is all about .NET code. However, this is independent of your application layer. CLR resides in SQL Server isolated of outside world, except for a thin layer that is introduced when you execute e.g. CREATE FUNCTION ... AS EXTERNAL. Then an interface between CLR and your application is created, and your application can use the code simply by calling that function. However, to write the function, one has to have some .NET background.

Comment: OH ok, now I understand. My requirement was just simply taking a table User_Properties and transposing it into and accessing it either via a UDF or view so that I can JOIN it with other tables in SQL. I do not know the columns in advance, therefore I needed a way to read the columns and then do the transposing, which I archived from my code.